# How do I simultaniously add and remove an image with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, for-loop

I have a section with a class of .canvas that I want to display images on top of (Its a picture of fries and i want the toppings to appear on them). I've managed to get the images to appear on the section with the class of canvas but they all stack on top of each other. How do I simultaneously add an image and remove the previous one with the same button, preferably using jQuery.

```js
$('#randomize').on('click', function() {
    const imgArray = $('.imgContainer');
    const randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length) + 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      
      if (randomImg === 1) {
        imgArray[0].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 2) {
        imgArray[1].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 3) {
        imgArray[2].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 4) {
        imgArray[3].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 5) {
        imgArray[4].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 6) {
        imgArray[5].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 7) {
        imgArray[6].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 8) {
        imgArray[7].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 9) {
        imgArray[8].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        imgArray[9].style.display = 'block';
      }
```

```css
.imgContainer {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
  <button id="randomize">Feed me</button>

<section class="canvas">
          <div class="imgContainer ketchup">
            <img src="./assets/images/ketchup.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer cheese">
            <img src="./assets/images/cheeseCurds.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="./assets/images/hotPeppers.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer bacon">
            <img src="./assets/images/baconBits.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer iceCream">
            <img src="./assets/images/iceCream.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer sprinkles">
            <img src="./assets/images/sprinkles.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer vaccine">
            <img src="./assets/images/vaccine.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer kitten">
            <img src="./assets/images/kitten.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer sock">
            <img src="./assets/images/dirtySock.png" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer face">
            <img src="./assets/images/brendanFraser.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </section>
```

The snippet will not run properly here because it does not contain the entire file. I'm just lost as to how I should add an image while removing the previous one.

Comment: Use `clearRect` and redraw the images you want and just leave out the images you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We really don't need all of that code just this bit, and we don't need to +1. Other wise you'll get an error as it's undefined:

```
const randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
imgArray[randomImg].style.display = 'block';
```

What we're doing is finding a random number between 0 and 6, since we have 7 images in the array. The click event handler will always change so there is no need for a loop or if statement.

```js
const imgArray = $('.imgContainer');
  
$('#randomize').on('click', function() {
    $('.imgContainer').hide();
    const randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
    $('.number-check').html(randomImg);
    imgArray[randomImg].style.display = 'block';
  });
```

```css
.imgContainer {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="randomize">Feed me</button>
<div>Lets check the number: <span class="number-check"></span></div>
<section class="canvas">
    <div class="imgContainer ketchup">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/122/200/300" alt="">
     </div>

          <div class="imgContainer cheese">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/144/200/300" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/198/200/300" alt="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/300" alt="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/200/300" alt="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="">
          </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: Wow that really cleaned it up. Is .number-check a function of jQuery?

Comment: @Shmeduard `$('.number-check')` is just a `<span>` that shows us the random number.  I could have just added a console.log, but I thought it would be a nice way to visibly show what it is. If you're talking about the `.html()` bit, that's the jQuery equivalent of `.innerHTML`

Comment: I was just curious because I have no class called number-class, so I was wondering if it was built in to the system because I couldn't find any info about it.

Comment: @Shmeduard No worries. I just added it to show the number being generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example just simply hide all before showing any.

```
 $('.imgContainer').hide();
```

```js
$('#randomize').on('click', function() {
    const imgArray = $('.imgContainer');
    const randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length) + 1;
    
$('.imgContainer').hide();

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      
      if (randomImg === 1) {
        imgArray[0].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 2) {
        imgArray[1].style.display = 'block';
      } else if (randomImg === 3) {
        imgArray[2].style.display = 'block';
      }
      
      
 } });
```

```css
.imgContainer {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="randomize">Feed me</button>

<section class="canvas">
          <div class="imgContainer ketchup">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.W8Ixmq-tCRyq4hwmsRrVqgHaDt%26pid%3DApi&f=1" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer cheese">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpmcvariety.files.wordpress.com%2F2019%2F12%2Fbaby-yoda-plush-toy-mattel-the-mandalorian.png%3Fw%3D1000%26h%3D563%26crop%3D1&f=1&nofb=1" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="imgContainer peppers">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitaltveurope.com%2Ffiles%2F2019%2F12%2FBaby-Yoda-Soup.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="">
          </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: @Shmeduard Please see edited answer, you don't need that code on every step, you just need it once on click and before showing other image. And if this works for you please consider marking this answer as accepted to mark this question as solved for others. Cheers.